Find an increase in value by multiple criteria
This is probably the long way around to do it, but im not sure how to shorten it. In the data frame df3 below, I have 2 sites where the depth ranges from 0.1 to 15.1 in 0.1 intervals. The density changes from surface to deep ocean. For each site, I need to find where the density increases by 0.03 after a depth of 10m. I need to produce two outputs:

In df 3, create a new column to write down the depth where the density change is seen. In my full dataset, each site has a depth from 0-2000m in 0.1 intervals, so the new column will have that single depth where density changes by 0.003, populated throughout that column (e.g., if its 15m, then 15 would be written in the column from 0-2000.)
Produce a new df (df4) that has the site and depth. For each site it would have just one value in the depth column that represents the depth where the change in density was found)

**I think I found a solution, which I have pasted below:
 depth <- seq(from = 0.1, to =15.1, by = 0.1)

 density <- c(NA,   NA, NA, NA, NA, 1027.073188,    1027.073543,    1027.073898, 1027.074253,   1027.074607,    1027.074962,    1027.075317,    1027.075672,    1027.076026, 1027.076381, 1027.076736, 1027.077118, 1027.077501,    1027.077884,    1027.078267,    1027.078649,    1027.079032,    1027.079415,    1027.079797,    1027.08018, 1027.080563,    1027.081026,    1027.081489,    1027.081952,    1027.082415,    1027.082878,    1027.08334, 1027.083803,    1027.084266,    1027.084729,    1027.085192,    1027.085663,    1027.086134,    1027.086605,    1027.087076,    1027.087547,    1027.088018,    1027.088489,    1027.08896, 1027.089431,    1027.089909,    1027.090387,    1027.090865,    1027.091344,    1027.091822,    1027.0923,  1027.092778,    1027.093256,    1027.093735,    1027.094213,    1027.094691,    1027.095162,    1027.095633,    1027.096104,    1027.096575,    1027.097046,    1027.097517,    1027.097987,    1027.098458,    1027.098929,    1027.0994,  1027.099871,    1027.100342,    1027.100813,    1027.101284,    1027.101755,    1027.102226,    1027.102697,    1027.103167,    1027.103638,    1027.104109,    1027.104556,    1027.105003,    1027.10545, 1027.105897,    1027.106344,    1027.106791,    1027.107237,    1027.107684,    1027.108131,    1027.108578,    1027.109041,    1027.109504,    1027.109967,    1027.110429,    1027.110892,    1027.111355,    1027.111818,    1027.112281,    1027.112744,    1027.113207,    1027.113683,    1027.114159,    1027.114635,    1027.115112,    1027.115588,    1027.116065,    1027.116542,    1027.117019,    1027.117497,    1027.117974,    1027.118451,    1027.118928,    1027.119406,    1027.119883,    1027.12036, 1027.120836,    1027.121312,    1027.121788,    1027.122264,    1027.12274, 1027.123216,    1027.123692,    1027.124167,    1027.124643,    1027.125119,    1027.125595,    1027.126071,    1027.126547,    1027.127023,    1027.127499,    1027.127975,    1027.128451,    1027.128926,    1027.129402,    1027.129878,    1027.130354,    1027.13083, 1027.131305,    1027.131781,    1027.132257,    1027.132732,    1027.133208,    1027.133684,    1027.134159,    1027.134635,    1027.135111,    1027.135587,    1027.136062,    1027.136538,    1027.137014,    1027.137489,    1027.137965,    1027.138441,    1027.138916,    1027.139392)

 df <- as.data.frame(cbind(depth, density))
 df$site <- 1

 df2 <- as.data.frame(cbind(depth, density-0.015))
 df2$site <- 2
 colnames(df2)[2] <- "density"

 df3 <- rbind(df, df2)

 miss <- function(x) ifelse(is.finite(x),x,NA)
 depths <- df3 %>% 
  group_by(site) %>%
   summarize(
    change=miss(depth[which( (c(rep(NA,99),  density[100:length(density)]) - density[100]) >= 0.003 )[1] ]),

)

Update
Try with {collapse}.
depth = seq(from = 0.1, to =15.1, by = 0.1)
density = c(NA,   NA, NA, NA, NA, 1027.073188,    1027.073543,    1027.073898, 1027.074253,   1027.074607,    1027.074962,    1027.075317,    1027.075672,    1027.076026, 1027.076381, 1027.076736, 1027.077118, 1027.077501,    1027.077884,    1027.078267,    1027.078649,    1027.079032,    1027.079415,    1027.079797,    1027.08018, 1027.080563,    1027.081026,    1027.081489,    1027.081952,    1027.082415,    1027.082878,    1027.08334, 1027.083803,    1027.084266,    1027.084729,    1027.085192,    1027.085663,    1027.086134,    1027.086605,    1027.087076,    1027.087547,    1027.088018,    1027.088489,    1027.08896, 1027.089431,    1027.089909,    1027.090387,    1027.090865,    1027.091344,    1027.091822,    1027.0923,  1027.092778,    1027.093256,    1027.093735,    1027.094213,    1027.094691,    1027.095162,    1027.095633,    1027.096104,    1027.096575,    1027.097046,    1027.097517,    1027.097987,    1027.098458,    1027.098929,    1027.0994,  1027.099871,    1027.100342,    1027.100813,    1027.101284,    1027.101755,    1027.102226,    1027.102697,    1027.103167,    1027.103638,    1027.104109,    1027.104556,    1027.105003,    1027.10545, 1027.105897,    1027.106344,    1027.106791,    1027.107237,    1027.107684,    1027.108131,    1027.108578,    1027.109041,    1027.109504,    1027.109967,    1027.110429,    1027.110892,    1027.111355,    1027.111818,    1027.112281,    1027.112744,    1027.113207,    1027.113683,    1027.114159,    1027.114635,    1027.115112,    1027.115588,    1027.116065,    1027.116542,    1027.117019,    1027.117497,    1027.117974,    1027.118451,    1027.118928,    1027.119406,    1027.119883,    1027.12036, 1027.120836,    1027.121312,    1027.121788,    1027.122264,    1027.12274, 1027.123216,    1027.123692,    1027.124167,    1027.124643,    1027.125119,    1027.125595,    1027.126071,    1027.126547,    1027.127023,    1027.127499,    1027.127975,    1027.128451,    1027.128926,    1027.129402,    1027.129878,    1027.130354,    1027.13083, 1027.131305,    1027.131781,    1027.132257,    1027.132732,    1027.133208,    1027.133684,    1027.134159,    1027.134635,    1027.135111,    1027.135587,    1027.136062,    1027.136538,    1027.137014,    1027.137489,    1027.137965,    1027.138441,    1027.138916,    1027.139392)
df = rbind(data.frame(depth, density, site = 1), 
           data.frame(depth, density = density - .015, site = 2))
df$density[254] = 1027.3

library(collapse)
df |> 
  fsubset(depth >= 10L) |>
  fgroup_by(site) |> 
  fsummarise(minDepth003 = depth[min(which(density - density[1] >= .003))])

  site minDepth003
1    1        10.7
2    2        10.3

Your toy data generation is unfortunate. - .015 is a constant, hence the results for site 1 and 2 would be identical. I changed the value of df$density[254] to 1027.3.
